# How to properly transition from NM-B to THWN from an attic to exterior surface mounted panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, junction-box

I am running 20 circuits using 12/2 NM-B cable that need to transition to a surface mounted box that is located on an exterior wall. I originally had the NM-B cable entering the knockouts located in back of the box. After posting my last question here, it seems I need to transition to THWN wire before entering the box. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I do not want any junction boxes in my living area. So I have several methods in mind to run wires to my box,

**Method 1**

Do I directly connect THWN wire from my receptacle all the way to the exterior breaker box? If so, how do I group/shield it in the attic without it separating?

**Method 2**

During my google search, there was a debate that it is a bad design to use a large junction box in the attic to transition from NM-B to stranded THWN wire but no one has offered a better solution. *(I did not reference it because it did not feel constructive)*

Should I install a large junction box in the attic and transition there? It would be at the very end of the attic next to the gable vent, a bit of crawling required but not impossible and will be visible. The THWN wire from the junction box inside the attic would be running through a top plate into the stud bays of my bedroom wall and exits into the back of my breaker box.

If neither of the above methods suffice, what would the best practice/solution be? I just want to do things right the first time with the drywall exposed.

Comment: You understand the THWN needs to be inside conduits, right?  And that there's a limit to 4 circuits per conduit?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica even when inside interior walls? There’s no way I can fit a conduit pipe in the back of the box it’s directly mounted on a stucco wall. I am using a Myers hub though. If that’s the case how are people handling the circuit issue? I was switching to thwn because I thought I could fit more conductors inside a conduit

Comment: You're up against 310.15(B)(3)(a) as far as 4 circuits per conduit. You can run 40 conductors in that pipe but they'll need to be #8 wire.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks! so even with let's say a 2 1/2" conduit, i'm still limited to just 4 circuits? i must have misunderstood the conduit fill chart

Comment: What is leading you to believe you need to transition the circuits to THWN in conduit before they enter the back of this (presumably a breaker) box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It’s a meter panel with breakers. And since it’s mounted in a “wet location” being that it’s outside you need to run THWN. I don’t know where the line is drawn because I was reading about “moisture” problems, premature failure, etc. I am using the knockouts directly behind the box and I was trying to run nm cable all the way.

Comment: As long as you've taken the trouble to do research and you have a citation, you'll make your question a lot better by linking to it rather than saying "saw it on Google".   And if I'm guessing correctly as to where you actually saw this (a Mike Holt post), the solution there was to use appropriate and sufficient water tight PVC conduit all the way to an appropriately sized interior box.  You could link to that, and ask specific questions about what would be appropriate and sufficient for your project.

Comment: @jay613 yeah let me apologize for that I meant to cite the thread. I felt it didn’t contribute enough and it looked like a lot of banter to me in that post to be honest.

Comment: There's another interesting discussion here in DIY about best practices for a big junction box with lots of circuits like the one you're contemplating in your attic.  You want to avoid building a spaghetti junction, and in fact you are required to achieve a "workmanlike" (or something like that) look, but you are not allowed to attach any of your connectors to the box.  So you end up trying to arrange free-floating Wago strips (or whatever you like) that maintain their position through the stiffness of the wires.  Which is harder if you use stranded in the PVC.   I'll look for the post later.

Comment: Given a very large pipe with low enough percentage fill, the 310.15(B)(3)(a) rules are suspended.  I am not sure if 2-1/2" is large enough.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica so the 4 circuit rule applies to 1/2” conduit and with 3/4” emt conduit im allowed (26 conductors) 13 circuits? I am referencing https://solutions.borderstates.com/resource/conduit-fill-table/

Comment: @jay613 I'm a big fan of wagos but I know that's an ongoing debate. If you can reference that discussion when you're free I'd be truly grateful. I'm big on craftsmanship so that's why I've been bombarding SE.

Comment: Concluding 4 circuits per conduit assumes won't-do-math worst case scenario (minimum conduit, minimum wire size, no MWBC'S). If you can arrange MWBC's to the attic box, then 8 circuits is 12 wires, so you would need to increase to 3/4", the de-rate factor would be 70% of 90°C #12 THWN 30A rating resulting in 21A, so you are still within 20A breaker size. There are other manipulations that could fit more larger wires in larger conduits.

Comment: I can't find it.   Someone was wiring up his basement and asked about a star configuration instead of daisy chaining things on a single circuit.   The discussion turned to how to wire up the box at the center of the star, I suggested some mounting clips from Wago and @Harper-ReinstateMonica explained how that would trigger the need for the whole assembly to undergo expensive certification as a "device".   You can neatly route all the wires,  arrange them around the box how you want, and make it pretty and maintainable, but the only attachment to the box is the conduit/cable entries.

Comment: Re: 3/4” emt conduit im allowed (26 conductors) , 26 is 1" emt. 26 current carrying conductors would require a derate factor of .45, resulting in 13.5A, next size larger standard size breaker would be 15A. See excerpt of actual NEC chapter 9, Annex C, Table C.1 for thwn emt conduit fill https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5G8IXnn9qOE/XX_5sxMnTkI/AAAAAAAAt1s/cZRbFTeH_rwePhWWQ8P1AzJDC3nYP_zmgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/NEC-EMT-Conduit-Fill-Table.png , Table 310.15(C)(1) for derating, Table 310.16 for wire ampacity,

Comment: @NoSparksPlease You're a life saver, I would have totally screwed that up. I misread the chart.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 - use conduit, done. That's the only way you CAN run THWN wires (under NEC rules, anyway) legally.

Method 2 - "seen on google" is not the same as "correct to code" - a junction box in an accessible attic is absolutely fine.

I happen to be a fan of method 1, even though I don't live in Chicago or NYC where that's generally required...

Re: Number of circuits discussion in the comments - use more than one conduit. 1/2" EMT will carry 4 circuits on 12Ga THHN, so 5 or 6 of those will get you done without the need for applying derate. No point in larger conduit unless you are using larger wires.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it’s a finished attic so method 1 is definitely gonna need some elbow grease. For the life of me I was not able to find any examples of anyone using this method, they all opted for method 2. I was using larger conduit in hopes to run less conduit and just fish more wires through it. Then again the problem is my exterior wall is built using 2 by 4 and you can only run such a large conduit.

Comment: `"seen on google" is not the same as "correct to code"` So much!!

Comment: Just finished sketching out the conduit path for method 1, gonna have to get creative with the bends unless I can use flexible conduit all the way through. If I were to proceed with my 2nd method, is it acceptable to tie all the ground wires from the 4 circuits together & run a single green THHN wire to the panel box? The junction box would be PVC.

Comment: Flexible conduit (metallic flex, ENT "Smurf tube", and LFNC, my absolute last choice) is widely available and acceptable. Yes, you can combine grounds, so long as the combined wire is as large as the largest ground wire (no harm in making it a size bigger either, but not *required.* Better than code is allowed, worse is not.)